# Initialize python array, every time it is called, where on of elements is dynamic

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic, python-3.10

I have an array in python:

```
ARR1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

and another array, which uses previous array random value for one of the elements

```
ARR2 = ['1', '2', '3', random.choice(ARR1)]
```

when I invoke `print(ARR2[])` I get random value on last position and this is fine.

Now I have a for in loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(ARR2[])
```

and I get the same random value every 3 times, like:

```
['1', '2', '3', 'B'] ['1', '2', '3', 'B'] ['1', '2', '3', 'B']
```

What I would like is, 5 random values, like:

```
['1', '2', '3', 'D'] ['1', '2', '3', 'A'] ['1', '2', '3', 'C']
```

How I understand it, the array ARR2, would have to be initialized, every time it is called in for loop.

Is it doable in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You created `ARR2` once and it already randomized a value when it was initialised.
Simply calling it again won't re-sample a random choice from `ARR1`

If you want it to generate a random choice each time you should do something like:

```py
import random
ARR1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
for _ in range(3):
   ARR2 = ["1", "2", "3", random.choice(ARR1)]
   print(ARR2)
```

Comment: That worked! Nesting ARR2[] creation inside a loop. Thank you @Tamir.

Comment: I upvoted, not sure how I accept it :-)